# File fingerprinting and security

Tags: api, security, hash

We're working on a file fingerprint for an API. We're having a discussion about how to fingerprint the file that will be send to the API.

There are a few options:

- MD5 the file -- great performance - but it has known collisions
- SHA1 the file -- worse performance - but more "secure" than MD5
- First MD5 the file -> next SHA1 the hash -- best performance

The files are >800mb.

What to do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a SHA-1 of the MD5 will give you as much collision as doing only the MD5, as you are just hashing the MD5 fingerprint (2 same MD5 -> 2 same SHA1)

Keep in mind that, whatever the algorythm is, you will always a chance of collision, as thin as it may be, as the only hash that would not ever colide for 2 different files are the files contents themself !

If your focus is uniqueness over the hash security (like when used for storing passwords), I would recommend this excellent analysis by Ian Boys (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633)